# Clear MARS backup warning: Validate

Tags: backup, azure, alert

I have alerts configured on the MARS agent, which I use to backup several servers. One server generates the error below weekly. I need help finding where to validate the encryption passphase. Related note: I am able to restore the data, so the message strikes me as bogus.
DESCRIPTION: The encryption passphase has not been validated to meet requirements. This is required to ensure successful restores.
RECOMMENDED ACTION(S): Please validate the encryption passphrase at the earliest by launching the console and clicking on Validate.
[MARS Alert Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaj08.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed this after a recent update of the backup agent version on the protected server. It's easy to miss so I searched around, apparently there are new passphrase requirements with the update. You will need to know the passphrase when you initially registered the server to the vault and enter it into a CLI window that appears by clicking the little link in the message at the top of the Microsoft Azure Backup UI on the protected server here:
[MARS-validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYtaA.png)

Gotta love MS always always finding different places to put stuff in the UI.

Comment: Holy cow. Thanks for the linked screen shot. Silly me, I was looking in the Actions panel for the Validate action.